# xpages - Very high memory usage of nhttp.exe (approx 100MB for one xpage)

Tags: xpages

I have a situation. I logged into my server machine and checked the memory usage for nhttp.exe. When I open an Xpage in my application, this jumped from ~30 MB to ~130 MB i.e. approx 100 MB for one single xpage for one user. Is this kind of memory usage normal for Xpages? My Xpage has a dojo enhanced grid with around 255 rows fetched from view using REST Service. I am not sure where should I concentrate.
Also the first time page load time is very high. Any ideas??[image: CPU Profiler Snapshot of Xpage - Reload]

Comment: What happens if more then one user opens a XPage? What is the memory usage of the task in this case?

Comment: And what happens if you use the preload feature of XPages?

Comment: This xpage is part of a template which approx 400 databases use. So I am not sure if I should use preload feature for this page.
Another user session does not add much to nhttp memory though. With two users it is ~ 147 MB!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no application is running (idle), the memory usage is low. As soon an application is started, it needs some memory (independently of the number of concurrent users) for internal usage. The startup of an application also needs some time (that's what the preload feature is for), and depends on how your application is designed and what resources are used (f.e. managed beans, scoped data, etc.) For me it sounds "normal" what you are describing.

There are a lot of tweaks possible to enhance the performance of an application, but without knowing further details it is impossible to give you a more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks Sven. I have taken a CPU Profiler snapshot using Xpages Toolbox to get some idea (see the attached image). What is perplexing me is why there are so many calls when I refreshed it only once. This snapshot is for single user single xpage. you can see that context.isDirectionRTL() and LTR() are executed multiple times. Even Xpage request itself (second last in the list) seems to be executed three times!!

Comment: You may have refreshed it only once. But the JSF lifecycle (XPages is built on JSF) has six phases for a partial refresh - there is a lot that needs to happen to take advantage of a server-side map when you're receiving text only and need to validate, convert and store as more than just text. What is the Total Time column calculated in? If that's milliseconds, the two longest elements are to do with pulling together the CSJS code required, not running SSJS.

Comment: It looks like context.isDirectionRTL() is calculated multiple times because you of multiple different SSJS calculations that use it. SSJS is just a string calculated at runtime. If five different components have the same SSJS, five different computations have to take place. XPages doesn't (and can't) know if you've written the same SSJS in five components. That's what dataContexts are for, to calculate SSJS once and reference the result via Expression Language in five different components.